# Connecting Multiple Ubuntu Orange Boxes

Tags: networking, maas, cloud

I would like to create a cluster of twenty machines and would like to know how this could work with two 10-node Ubuntu Orange Boxes. In the marketing material it says that the boxes can be "daisy-chained" together.

- Is there an optimum way to connect them? Is a single ethernet cable the only option?
- Can all the nodes on box 2 be controlled through maas on box 1?
- What about bottlenecks, would there be a limit of 1Gb/s between the boxes?
- How can I get box2 to accept IP addresses from box1?
- What if I get a third box? :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is all very, very doable!  In fact, I've done it myself (as the lead architect behind the Orange Box).

The only gotcha, is that typically, the Orange Box is shipped from TranquilPC with each node's AMT (out of band power management system) hard coded to static IP addresses.  Node1 get's IP 10.14.4.11, Node2 get's IP 10.14.4.12, etc. to Node9 with 10.14.4.19.  That's on each individual Orange Box shipped.

What you'll want to do is instead configure each node in Orange Box #2 to have different static IPs, perhaps 10.14.4.20 - 10.14.4.29, and perhaps Orange Box #3 to have 10.14.4.30 - 10.14.4.39.

That'll take you a few minutes on each node to setup, and you'll need a keyboard/mouse/monitor, and you'll have to login to BIOS/AMT/MEBx to set this up.  But you only have to do it once per node.

Everything else should "just work".  MAAS and Juju can both handle hundreds of nodes easily.

A single ethernet cable will definitely connect them.  All nodes will be registered and boot off of Node0 on your first Orange Box (or wherever you have MAAS/Juju installed).

There will be 1 gigabit of bandwidth between the two gigabit switches.  You could, perhaps look into port aggregation on the D-Link switch (which is listening on 10.90.90.90), to combine a couple of ports.  Note that I have not, personally, tried this, but theoretically, it might work :-)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response - wasn't expecting it to come from such an authoritative source! For 'port aggregation' would that be LACP (aka 802.3ad?) - I didn't think the D-Link DGS-1100-16 supported that protocol?